# Standard way for breaking out of recursion in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme

I am writing my first program in scheme. I get pretty deep into recursion because I basically interpret a program for a simple robot which can have nested procedure calls.

If I find a violation I need to stop interpreting the program and return the last valid state.

I've solved it by declaring a global variable `(define illegalMoveFlag 0)` and then setting it via `set!`.

It works fine, but I guess my tutor won't like it (because it's not functional approach I guess)

Other approach I've thought about is to add an error parameter to every function I call recursively in the program. I don't quite like it because it would make my code far less readable, but I guess it's more 'functional'.

Is there maybe a third way I didn't think about? And can my approach be justified in this paradigm, or is it basically a code smell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this was your first Scheme program, you probably just need to introduce a conditional expression, `cond`, in order to avoid further recursion when you reach the end. For example:

```
; sum : natural -> natural
;  compute the sum 0+1+...+max
(define (sum max)
  (define (sum-helper i sum-so-far)
    (if (> i max)
        sum-so-far
        (sum-helper (+ i 1) (+ sum-so-far i))))
  (sum-helper 0 0))

(display (sum 10))
(newline)
```

However, if you need a traditional `return` to return like `longjmp` in C, you will need to store and use an escape continuation. This can be done like this:

```
(define (example)
  (let/ec return
    (define (loop n)
      (if (= n 100000)
          (return (list "final count: " n))
          (loop (+ n 1))))
    (loop 0)))

(display (example))
```

If `let/ec` is not defined in your Scheme implementation, then prefix your program with:

```
(define-syntax let/ec 
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ return body ...)
     (call-with-current-continuation
      (lambda (return)
        body ...))]))
```

UPDATE:

Note that `cond` has an `=>` variant:

```
(cond
  [(call-that-can-fail)
    => (lambda (a) <use-a-here>))]
  [else <do-something-else>])
```

If the call succeeds then the first, clause is
taken and the result is bound to a. If the call fails,
then the else clause is used.

Comment: Nicest answer so far. However I can't use the first method that easily. To be more specific I use something like (let* ((a (call-that-can-fail)) (b (other-call-that-can-fail a))) ... ) If a fails I need to stop b from executing (I know it can be done via condition but it will be uglier than my current solution). I guess I will use the continuation, It will make my function reentrant, which my solution with global variable isn't.

Comment: Maybe you can use an `=>` clause in `cond`? See the example above.

Answer (score 5):

The usual way to stop recursing is, well, to stop recursing. i.e., don't call the recursive function any longer. :-)

If that is too hard to do, the other way to break out of something is to capture a continuation at the top level (before you start recursing), then invoke the continuation when you need to "escape". Your instructor may not like this approach, though. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the built-in procedure `error`, like so:

```
(error "Illegal move") ; gives ** Error: Illegal move
```

This will raise an exception and stop interpreting the program (though I suspect this may not be what you are looking for).

You can also provide additional arguments, like this:

```
(error "Illegal move: " move) ; gives ** Error: Illegal move: <move>
```

Comment: I guess this won't help me, because my program will be also auto-evaluated and this would break the specs.

Answer (score 1):

You can exit of a recursion (or from any other process) using a continuation. Without knowing more specifics, I'd recommend you take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/cont.html) of your interpreter.

Comment: This looks interesting, didn't know about it :) But is it somewhat normal approach? Or is it like using goto in C?

Comment: @HonzaBrabec a continuation is an extremely general and flexible flow control mechanism. Exceptions, the "return" keyword, and yes, [goto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goto#Continuations) can be implemented in terms of continuations. But I wouldn't call it a _normal_ way to solve a problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Make illegalMoveFlag a paramter in the function instead of a global variable

I'll give you a simple example with factorials

ie:
0! = 1
n! = n * (n - 1)! when n (1 ... infinity)

lets call this a recursive factorial

```
(define (fact-r n)
    (if 
       [eq? n 0] 
       1 
       (* n (fact-r (- n 1)))
    )
)
```

An alternative would be to use a parameter to the function to end the recursion
Lets call it iterative factorial

```
(define (fact-i n total)
  (if 
      (eq? n 0) 
      total
      (fact-i (- n 1) (* n total))
  )
)
```

total needs to start at 1 so we should make another function to make using it nicer

```
(define (nice-fact n)
  (fact-i n 1))
```

You could do something similar with illegalMoveFlag to avoid having a global variable
As far as avoiding using set! goes, we'll probably need more information.

In some cases its still rather hard to avoid using it. Scheme is fully turing complete without the use of set! however when it comes to accessing an external source of information such as a database or a robot set! can become the only practical solution...